# What does the expression &Proc.new do in a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found usage of `&Proc.new` in the rails sources:

```
# rails/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb
def routes
  @routes ||= ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.new
  @routes.append(&Proc.new) if block_given?
  @routes
end
```

I don't understand how the expression `&Proc.new` works.

I wrote similar code and it failed:

```
def method_name
  &Proc.new if block_given?
end
proc = method_name{ puts 'Hello world!' }
proc.call
```

I received a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected &
    &Proc.new if block_given?
```

- What does the expression `&Proc.new` do in a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` has a special meaning in argument list - when used as prefix for Proc object it passes it as block to method being called. Within method body it's just a binary operator.

Answer (score 4):

First you should know and understand what blocks and Procs are. Basically they are the way ruby provides closures. [Here](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) is a good link.

The unary ampersand operator in ruby has 3 uses (all of them related to blocks and Procs):

- If applied to an argument in a method definition, then the implicit block parameter is stored as a Proc using the argument name.
- If applied to a Proc in a method call, then the block contained in the Proc is passed as the implicit block parameter. It preserves whether the Proc is a lambda or not. Methods are always lambdas.
- If applied to other object in a method call, the method #to_proc is called and the resulting Proc is passed as in the second case.

[The & Operator in Ruby](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby) explains it in detail.

Comment: Thank you for information. I know what Proc and lambda are, but as it turned  out, my knowledge are not perfect

Answer (score 1):

If Proc.new is called from inside a method without any arguments of its own, it will return a new Proc containing the block given to its surrounding method.

```
def foo
  Proc.new.call
end

foo { puts "hello world" }
# hello world
```

This means that it is now possible to pass a block between methods without using the &block parameter:

```
class C
  def bar
    puts "called bar..."
    baz &Proc.new
  end

  def baz
    puts "called baz..."
    yield
  end
end

C.new.bar { puts "called block..." }
# called bar...
# called baz...
# called block...
```

This trick gets used by Rails at

```
# File railties/lib/rails/engine.rb, line 533
def routes
  @routes ||= ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.new_with_config(config)
  @routes.append(&Proc.new) if block_given?
  @routes
end
```

More details at

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L532-L538
- https://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html
- http://confreaks.tv/videos/rubyconf2010-zomg-why-is-this-code-so-slow